# How to run multiple request sequentially in Apache Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an Application where i have to do load test.Its like i have request A and B,and i have to test with 10 users and request should go like first request - A,B ,second request - A,B with ramp up period 0.

Could Any one help on this.I tried doing with Simple controller but the request are sent randomly and fring error

Comment: what errors are you getting? It is a good practice to see the JMeter log to pinpoint your issue. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321662/running-multiple-thread-groups-sequentially-in-jmeter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program)

Answer (score 4):

Check the box for "**Run Thread Groups Consecutively**" in your test plan. It will send your request A and B for first users then for second users and so on.

See this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to wait until 1st user is done before starting 2nd one the fastest and the easiest solution would be setting `Number of Threads` to 1 and loop requests A and B 10 times in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration.

[image: JMeter Thread Group Configuration Example]

---

If for any reason you need to have 10 concurrent users but executing requests sequentially you can go for [Inter-Thread Communication JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) which allows synchronizing JMeter threads (even residing in different Thread Groups)

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Inter Thread Communication Plugin]

Comment: I have 10 users in my CSV file and I want to process the each user one by one, After completion of one user second user will be processed accordingly. So, In the above picture If I set `loop count to 10`, `No. of Threads to 1` then will it takes the different user each time from the CSV file ??