# How to execute Thread Groups in order

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My Test plan in look like this:

```
Test Plan
   |- Thread Group A
   |     |- HTTP request 1
   |- Thread Group B
   |     |- HTTP request2
   |     |- HTTP request3
   |- Thread Group C
   |     |- HTTP request4
   |     |- HTTP request5
   |- Thread Group D
   |     |- HTTP request6
```

when i run it, it don't execute threads in order! `(B -> A-> D -> C)`
How can i fix it please ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321662/running-multiple-thread-groups-sequentially-in-jmeter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running multiple Thread Groups sequentially in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321662/running-multiple-thread-groups-sequentially-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JMeter executes [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) simultaneously, if you want JMeter to execute them one by one - tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

[image]

You can also consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) in order to setup some custom rules for requests execution in case if request in one thread group needs to be executed after specific request in another thread group.